# Django ValidationError EmailField

Tags: django

I've been struggling with this error below.  I am trying to checkout a user as guest with email but I get a validation error: 
ValidationError at /register/guest['“NU1@company.com” value must be either True or False.']

```
next_ = request.GET.get('next')
next_post = request.POST.get('next')
redirect_path = next_ or next_post or None
if form.is_valid():
    email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
    new_guest_email = GuestEmail.objects.create(email=email)
    request.sesssion['guest_email_id'] = new_guest_email.id
    if is_safe_url(redirect_path, request.get_host()):
        return redirect(redirect_path)
    else:
        return redirect('/register/')
return redirect('/register/')
```

Comment: What is `form` here? What does the `Form` class look like?

Comment: class GuestForm(forms.Form): email = forms.EmailField()

Comment: Solved! Checked my models and I was calling a BooleanField instead for EmailField.

Comment: That part of source code is not in the question it seems.

Comment: Its not.  I went back through to check for the 100th time and finally ran across it.  Thanks for helping.